# Equation of a wave

Tags: waves, definition, differential-equations

Is there any equation of wave that do not obey the differential equation:
$$\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial t^2}=v^2\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial x^2}~ ?$$
and how can I know whether a given equation (equation for $y$) is a wave equation or not?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. "Wave" does not have a universally accepted rigorous definition. Thus, some people call some non-linear PDEs "non-linear wave equation".

Comment: what are other forms of wave except this PDE mentioned in the question..  Is there any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the most general definition of a wave is *a field evolving accordingly to an initial value problem for the field and its first n time derivatives* ($n$ varies with the equation). Such a definition allows us to know if a particular partial differential equation corresponds to waves or not. Moreover, it is sufficiently general to include the solution of [Hyperbolic partial differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_partial_differential_equation) (linear and non-linear) as well as discontinuous shock waves.

Therefore, there is a huge number of equations of waves not coinciding with D'Alembert's equation.
A couple of equations of wave departing more from D'Alembert is as follows:

- linear dispersive waves (obtained from the Fourier transform of D'Alembert's equation with a wave-vector dependence of the phase velocity $v$;
- non-linear waves like the [Sine-Gordon equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine-Gordon_equation):
  $$
  \frac{\partial^2y}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial x^2}+\sin(x)=0
  $$
  or  the [Korteweg-De Vries equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korteweg%E2%80%93De_Vries_equation):
  $$
  \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial^3y}{\partial x^3}-6 y \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=0.
  $$
  Of course, also the time-dependent Schrödinger equation is an equation of wave.

Answer (score 1):

This wave equation is linear. There are however non-linear extensions with non linear waves called kinks and solitons.

Answer (score 1):

We can define a wave in the following way: There is a $y = f(x)$ over a domain. For example, the topography along a road.

Now let's suppose another frame of reference travelling in the $-x$ direction, with a speed $-v$. It can be a car on the road. For the road's frame, the position of the car is $x_c = x_0 - vt$. In the frame of the car, that point is labeled as $x' = 0$. Any other point $x$ of the road's frame, from the perspective of the car is $x' = x - x_0 + vt$.

For the car, the road with all its hills and depressions is travelling with speed $v$, and the passing slopes are like a travelling wave. The same topographic function, when using the coordinates of the car is: $y = f(x'- vt + x_0)$.

If we make the derivative with respect to time, and using the chain rule:
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial ((x'- vt + x_0)}\frac{\partial (x'- vt + x_0)}{\partial t} = -v\frac{\partial f}{\partial ((x'- vt + x_0)}$$

The second derivative with respect to time:
$$\frac{\partial ^2y}{\partial t^2} = v^2\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial (x'- vt + x_0)^2}$$

Making the same procedure for the double derivative with respect to x':
$$\frac{\partial ^2y}{\partial x'^2} = \frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial (x'- vt + x_0)^2} $$

Resulting in the PDE:
$$v^2\frac{\partial ^2y}{\partial x'^2} = \frac{\partial ^2y}{\partial t^2}$$

So, by this concept of wave, that is the PDE.

Comment: There are more waves in heaven and earth, Claudio,
Than are dreamt of in your D'Alembert's equation. :-)

Comment: Do sum of two wave with different velocity and frequency follow this PDE?

Comment: @GiorgioP yes, I saw your answer. My approach supposes that there is a frame for which the field is static, which helps to visualize most plane waves. But this special frame doesn't exist for other cases (as EM waves for example).

Comment: @MDHossain the velocity must be $v$, the same for both waves. The frequency doesn't matter. Or: we can have parallel roads with different topographies. But the velocity of the car's are the same, otherwise it is a different PDE.